# Sum of perfect squares to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

In [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%80%A6), the method of computing $1+2+\dots$ is outlined. Is there a similar method for computing $1^2+2^2+\dots$? What about for the general power $n$? (That is, $1^n+2^n+\dots$)

Comment: This is homework?

Comment: [This question may prove useful](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/155166/25554)

Comment: check this [wolframalpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html) article

Answer (score 8):

To go to infinity you will need the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

For powers $n$ the result is given by $\zeta(-n)=-\frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1}$.
(this means $0$ for $n$ even since $B_n$ is a [Bernoulli number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number))

The story is that $\displaystyle f(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{k^s}$ was found convergent for $s>1$ (Euler solved the famous 'Basel' case $s=2$) so that a function was searched later that worked for any complex $s\not= 1$ (Riemann).

For negative integer values of $s$ you'll get your limits.
In the wikipedia section kindly linked by Will Jagy note the Bernoulli numbers  : that's what you really need! (Euler's teacher was Jean Bernoulli by the way...).

For the story of Euler's contribution see Sandifer's ['How Euler did it'](http://www.maa.org/editorial/euler/How%20Euler%20Did%20It%2023%20Bernoulli%20numbers.pdf).

Ramanujan rediscovered your series too but that's another [story](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38731/values-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-and-the-ramanujan-summation-how-strong-is).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values

Comment: Sandifer's excellent articles "How Euler Did It" are still available in [Euler's archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/index.html) :  
[Sums of powers](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2009-06.pdf), [Bernoulli numbers](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2005-09.pdf), [Multi-zeta functions](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2008-01.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There is no similar method to compute $1^2+2^2+\cdots$. However, there is a trick for you to compute any finite term series sum like $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^n$.

To find such a sum, you first need to know the sums $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{k^p}, \forall p<n$.  Then you can use the following trick to find  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^n$.

1. Rewrite  $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m+1}k^{n+1}-(m+1)^{n+1}$$
2. Rewrite the first term $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m+1}k^{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{0}0^{n+1}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m+1}k^{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}(1+k)^{n+1}$$
3. Expand $(1+k)^{n+1}$ using binomial coefficients, i.e. $$(1+k)^{n+1}=\sum\limits_{p=0}^{{n+1}}{{n+1}\choose p}k^p1^{{n+1}-p}=\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n+1}{{n+1}\choose p}k^p=k^{n+1}+\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n}{{n+1}\choose p}k^p$$
4. Put these pieces together, then you have
   $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m+1}k^{n+1}-(m+1)^{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}\left(k^{n+1}+\sum\limits_{q=0}^{n}{{n+1}\choose p}k^p\right)-(m+1)^{n+1}\\=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^{n+1}+\sum\limits_{q=0}^{n}{{n+1}\choose p}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^p\right)-(m+1)^{n+1}$$
   implying that$$\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n}{{n+1}\choose p}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^p\right)-(m+1)^{n+1}=0$$ 
   Therefore, we have
   $${{n+1}\choose n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^n=(m+1)^{n+1}-\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n-1}{{n+1}\choose p}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^p\right)$$
   namely 
   $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^n=\frac{1}{n+1}\left((m+1)^{n+1}-{{n+1}\choose n-1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^{n-1}-\cdots-{{n+1}\choose 1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k-{{n+1}\choose 0}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}1\right)$$
   Since you know for $n=1$$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$, then use the above trick you can derive $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^2$, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^3\cdots$,$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^{n-1}$, and finally $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^n$.

Comment: This is, sadly, not what the OP is asking.