# Value of Riemann zeta function at $-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

This claim is false $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-(-1)}= \zeta(-1)=-1/12$.

The error is that we should

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n ^1)^{-1}=(0)^{-1}$.

Am I correct? It's difficult to say that an infinite sum like that don't diverge and that sum of positive numbers can give negative number.

Comment: $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}$ is only true when $\text{Re}(s)>1$.  To evaluate at $s=-1$ you would need to use the functional equation.  Point being: the error you're making is with your second equality: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-(-1)}\neq \zeta(-1)$.

Comment: Also, no: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n^1)^{-1}\neq (0)^{-1}$.  It seems as though you're thinking that $\sum (\text{stuff})^{-1}=(\sum \text{stuff})^{-1}$, which is not true, and you seem to be be thinking that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n=0$, which is not true (perhaps you're not thinking these things, but it is the only way I can interpret what you wrote above "i'm i correct?").

Comment: Related: [proof of Riemann's functional equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/586870/)

Comment: Also related: [Values of the Riemann Zeta function and the Ramanujan Summation](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/38731/)

Comment: *It's difficult to say that an infinite sum like that don't diverge and that sum of positive numbers can give negative number.* - Difficult ? Yes ! But *impossible* ? No ! ;-)

Comment: Ralph Mellish's statement above is correct/is a good answer.  But, for historical reasons: Ramanujan famously sent a letter to University College in London containing the expression: $1+2+3+\cdots+\infty = -\frac{1}{12}$.  This is meaningless/mathematically wrong.  But, it exhibits a shorthand resembling the zeta function, which is to be expected from someone who received no formal training in mathematics (and thus, wouldn't follow *all* conventions relating to definitions of functions, etc.).

Comment: Dear anorton, «meaningless/mathematically wrong» is... an overstatement, perhaps. There are various notions of summability beside convergence of the sequence of partial sums.

Answer (score 1):

Use the functional equation:
$$\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{-1+s}\Gamma(1-s)\sin\frac{\pi s}2\zeta(1-s)\;,\;\;s\neq1\implies$$

$$\zeta(-1)=\frac1{2\pi^2}\cdot1\cdot(-1)\zeta(2)=-\frac1{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

*Ralph Mellish said* :

> $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}$  is only true when Re(s)>1. To evaluate at s=−1 you would need to use the functional equation. Point being: the error you're making is with your second equality: ∑∞n=1n−(−1)≠ζ(−1). 
>   Also, no: ∑∞n=1(1/n1)−1≠(0)−1. It seems as though you're thinking that ∑(stuff)−1=(∑stuff)−1, which is not true, and you seem to be be thinking that ∑∞n=11/n=0, which is not true (perhaps you're not thinking these things, but it is the only way I can interpret what you wrote above "i'm i correct?"). –

but he doesnt know that this trick is often used in string theory which is the final theory of everything

(this was posted as an answer in the place of a comment because have small inductive reputation)

Comment: "in string theory which is the final theory of everything" Errm, what?

Comment: My area of interest is mathematics related to string theory, I am very well aware of the arguments made there regarding zeta functions.  That doesn't change that fact that it is mathematically incorrect.

Comment: oh... sorry....

Comment: admin please delete my answer because it is false

Comment: but i have seen an article in terence tao blog about that and he says that thas right

Comment: "Final TOE": Is this written tongue-in-cheek?

Comment: No need to be sorry, those sorts of arguments are interesting.  And should you find the blog again, I'll gladly check out what he has to say.  :)

Comment: Also, I'm far from perfect: I could simply be wrong.  ;)

Comment: Where does Terence say that *what* is right, @user119235?