# How does the sum of the series “$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6\ldots$” to infinity = “$-1/12$”?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity

(*I was requested to edit the question to explain why it is different that a proposed duplicate question. This seems counterproductive to do here, inside the question it self, but that is what I have been asked by the site and moderators. There is no way for me to vote against their votes. So, here I go: Please stop voting this as a duplicate so quickly, which will eventually lead to this question being closed off. Yes, the other question linked to asks the same math, but any newcomer to the problem who was exposed to it via physics, as I was, will prefer this question instead of the one that is purely mathematically. I beg the moderators to not be pedantic on this one. This question spills into physics, which is why I did the cross post to the physics forum as well.*)

How does the sum of the series “1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6…” to infinity = “-1/12”, in the context of physics?

I heard Lawrence Krauss say this once during a debate with Hamza Tzortzis (http://youtu.be/uSwJuOPG4FI). I found a transcript of another debate between Krauss and William Lane Craig which has the same sum. Here is the paragraph in full:

> Let’s go to some of the things Dr. Craig talked about. In fact, the
>   existence of infinity, which he talked about which is
>   self-contradictory, is not self-contradictory at all. Mathematicians
>   know precisely how to deal with infinity; so do physicists. We rely on
>   infinities. In fact, there’s a field of mathematics called “Complex
>   Variables” which is the basis of much of modern physics, from
>   electro-magnetism to quantum mechanics and beyond, where in fact we
>   learn to deal with infinity; without the infinities we couldn’t do the
>   physics. We know how to sum infinite series because we can do complex
>   analysis. Mathematicians have taught us how. It’s strange and very
>   unappetizing, and in fact you can sum things that look ridiculous. For
>   example, if you sum the series, “1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6…” to infinity,
>   what’s the answer? “-1/12.” You don’t like it? Too bad! The
>   mathematics is consistent if we assign that. The world is the way it
>   is whether we like it or not.

-- Lawrence Krauss, debating William Lane Craig, March 30, 2011

Source: http://www.reasonablefaith.org/the-craig-krauss-debate-at-north-carolina-state-university

**CROSS POST:** I'm not sure if I should post this in mathematics or physics, so I posted it in both. Cross post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92739/how-does-the-sum-of-the-series-1-2-3-4-5-6-to-infinity-1-12

**EDIT:** I did not mean to begin a debate on why Krauss said this. I only wished to understand this interesting math. He was likely trying to showcase Craig's lack of understanding of mathematics or logic or physics or something. Whatever his purpose can be determined from the context of the full script that I linked to above. Anyone who is interested, please do. Please do not judge him out of context. Since I have watched one of these debates, I understand the context and do not hold the lack of a full breakdown as being ignorant. Keep in mind the debate I heard this in was different from the debate above.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Summability

Comment: "We know how to sum infinite series because we can do complex analysis" ...Really?!

Comment: Good idea, just did.

Comment: Sorry, someone edited this while I was editing it, and I have no idea how to see what changes were made.

Comment: related: [Value of Riemann zeta function at $−1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/628022/)

Comment: I found this also very hard to understand. This video helped be to get a better picture on that  (youtu.be/wt6ngy6pDws)

Answer (score 8):

As a Physicist, I'll admit that the above is one of the many abuses of mathematics that occurs in theoretical physics like in string theory and in quantum field theory. In fact, that pseudo "analytic continuation" of $1+2+3+\dots$ being $-1/12$ using the Riemann's zeta function is done as a drop in for that infinite series which actually does occur in the development of string theory to sort of do away with it. Many other such upsetting things happen in physics like that.

Call it shameless, but physicists are that way. Kind of like how we shriek when chemists think that electronic configurations are actually accurate above hydrogen, the "lesser field" is always less rigorous than the antecedent...

Comment: Wow, I would love to learn so much more from you.

Answer (score 7):

That is either a joke or a proof of ignorance: we have Riemann's zeta funcion

$$\zeta(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}\;\;,\;\;\text{which converges for}\;\;\text{Re}(s)>1$$

If we put $s=-1$, we indeed get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{-1}}=1+2+3+\ldots$$

and we know that the zeta function's value at $\;z=-1\;$ is $\;-\frac1{12}\;$ ....**but** ...the Riemann zeta function at that value is **not** the above infinite series but way another thing (google" functional equation for zeta function), and from it, we get that value of $\;-\frac1{12}\;$ .

To put $\;1+2+3+\ldots=-\frac1{12}\;$ is like a mathematical joke (don't debate the humour...), and whoever who actually claims this is probably an ignorant of the above facts.

Comment: Like you did not want to debate the humor, I did not mean to begin a debate on why Krauss said it, only to understand this interesting math. He was likely trying to showcase Craig's lack of understanding of mathematics or logic or physics. It can be determined by reading the full script that I linked to above. Anyone who is interested, please do!

Comment: *whoever who actually claims this is probably an ignorant* - You mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) guy ? :-)

Comment: @Lucian: Ramanujan too was aware that this is not the standard meaning or value of the sum, but simply a way of assigning a value to divergent series (that have no sum). He wrote (I'm [quoting from Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), emphasis mine): "I told him that the sum of an infinite number of terms of the series: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + · · · = −1/12 **under my theory.** If I tell you this you will at once point out to me the lunatic asylum as my goal. [...]"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I'm not quite sure why you'd think that those three words mean what you say they mean... :-) Yes, Ramanujan was indeed ignorant of these things at that time: that didn't stop him from being one of the greatest mathematicians that have ever lived. In the mean time, us fully-knowledgeable and properly-schooled persons, what did we ever achieve that could even come close ? :-)

Comment: @Lucian: No, Ramanujan was *not* ignorant of the obvious fact that the sum is divergent. On what basis do you make the claim that he was? He may have had low standards of proof, but he was already at the time extremely competent at coming up with the right answers, with a matchless intuition as well. He only meant that he had come up with a way of assigning values to divergent series.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: A man with a single watch knows always the exact time. A man with two watches never does. People for whom things are ‘obvious’ belong into the former category. Ramanujan, in the latter. He's just one example among many, but the rest lived before the modern era.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: As I see it there isn't a reason for an argument. You're emphasizing "*under my theory*" as "not in the standard sense" while Lucian's emphasizing it as "In a real and meaningful sense". No disagreement on facts

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy: The question is about the word "ignorant". Lucian claims that Ramanujan was *ignorant* of certain basic facts, while from what we know of his early education (read Carr's synopsis, etc.) and accomplishments (problems he submitted to Indian math journals, etc.) there is simply no way he would not be aware of this. It was his genius that he was able to see that *despite* this, it might still make sense to develop a theory for divergent series, but there is absolutely no reason to claim that he did it out of *ignorance*.

Comment: @Lucian: You're just saying fancy things, but I'm asking again: on what basis do you claim that he was **ignorant** (i.e. unaware) of divergent series? And not, as seems obvious to me from reading his biographies and early articles, that he developed his theory despite being aware of these facts?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It's clear from [his correspondence with Hardy and others](http://books.google.com/books?id=Of5G0r6DQiEC&printsec=frontcover), as well as from their correspondence with each other about him. They recommended a book to him (a manual, basically): Bromwich, *An Introduction to the Theory of Infinite Series*. One of these contemporary correspondents wrote that even in his time at some prestigious British university, these things were still poorly understood, so that it came as no surprise that Ramanujan, lacking proper or rigorous training, faced some of these same difficulties.

Comment: The fact that it is not the standard meaning of a sum does not mean that it is a joke or ignorant.

Answer (score 4):

He probably meant [Ramanujan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation), which assigns divergent series a number. This is still not "The Answer" to the sum of the series, as this is clearly infinity, it's just a number *assigned* to a series.

If that is indeed what he meant, it rather ruins his argument, but we'll assume it was said in the heat of the debate.

Comment: Yes, but to be fair... Although we conventionally interpret "The Answer" to an infinite series to be its "sum", i.e. the topological limit of the sequence of partial sums, that answer isn't logically privileged. It just happens to be a useful thing to do with most series, most of the time.

Comment: @ChrisCulter - but to the audience he's trying to wow it is, and the fact that he meant the improper limit of $\sum ne^{−ϵn}$ instead of the regular sum is rather demagogic IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in another answer, the "result" is related to the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(z)$, which can be defined by the series $\zeta(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-z}$ when $\text{Re}(z)>1$.  This can be extended by analytic continuation to all $z$; the unique result is the zeta function, which has a simple pole at $z=1$ and is holomorphic on the rest of $\mathbb{C}$.

The process of analytic continuation is interesting in its own right, and you may want to know how it works in this case.  One way of describing it is that you can use the value of a function and its first $n$ derivatives at a point $z_0$ to estimate the value of the function and its first $n-1$ derivatives at a second point $z_1$ (and if $|z_1-z_0|$ is small enough, this process will converge as $n\rightarrow \infty$).  You can then estimate the value of the function and its first $n-2$ derivatives at a third point $z_2$ (close enough to $z_1$), and so on.  By tracing out a path that avoids singularities (such that $z_{i+1}$ is always within the radius of convergence of the Taylor series expansion at $z_{i}$), you can define the value of the function outside the original region, purely in terms of the function's value and derivatives ("germ") at a single point.  In this case, for instance, you might choose $z=2$ to start from; the germ then depends only on the sums
$$
\frac{d^k}{dz^k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-z}\bigg\vert_{z=2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\log^k n}{n^2}.
$$